# What is the difference between min-instances and min-idle-instances in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to understand the difference between min-instances & min-idle-instances?

I saw documentation on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements but I am not able to differentiate between the two.

My use case:
I want at least 1 instance always up, as otherwise in most of the cases GAE would take time in creating instance causing my requests to time out (in case of basic scaling).

It should stay up, no matter if there is traffic or not, and if a request comes it should immediately serve it. If request volume grows then it should scale.

Which one I should use?

Comment: Did you make your app engine always on? Can you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211259/long-warmup-40-seconds-on-my-appengine-standard-java11/62212007?noredirect=1#comment110052101_62212007? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The `min-idle-instances` make reference to the instances that are ready to support your application in case you receive **high traffic** or **CPU intensive tasks**, unlike the `min_instances` which are the instances used to process the incoming request **immediately**. I suggest you to take a look on [this link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/0ZBLsyc51gk/rX7PT6-2AAAJ) to have a deeper explanation of idle instances.

Based on this, since your use-case is focused on serve the incoming requests immediately, I think you should rather go with the `min_instances` functionality and use the `min-idle-instances` only in case you want to be ready for sudden load spikes.

Answer (score 5):

The `min-instances` configuration applies to *dynamic* instances while `min-idle-instances` applies to *idle/resident* instances.

See also:

- [Introduction to instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#introduction_to_instances) for a description of the 2 instance types
- [Why do more requests go to new (dynamic) instances than to resident instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103831/why-do-more-requests-go-to-new-dynamic-instances-than-to-resident-instance/45120896#45120896) for a bit more details

Comment: Nice to know this, but strangely when I give min-idle-instances config, then also I see dynamic instance created only in App Engine Console's -> Instances Page. where I should have seen instance type as Resident isn't it?

Comment: I never used that config, so I don't know how they appear in the console. But do you see them handling traffic?

Comment: nope, it still spawns 2 instances so traffic is mostly being handled by other.

Comment: The ones handling no (of very little) traffic are most likely the resident ones. I read somewhere an explanation that once the resident ones need to handle traffic peaks they become dynamic and fresh resident ones are being started to take their place according to the the `min-idle-instances` config

Answer (score 5):

`min_instances`: the minimum number of instances running at any time, traffic or no traffic, rain or shine.

`min_idle_instances`: the minimum of idle (or "unused") instances running over the currently used instances. Example: you automatically scaled to 5 app engine instances that are receiving requests, by setting `min_idle_instances` to 2, you will be running 7 instances in total, the 2 "extra" instances are idle and waiting in case you receive more load. The goal is that when load raises, your users don't have to wait the load time it takes to start up an instance.

**IMPORTANT: you need to configure warmup requests for that to work**

**IMPORTANT2: you'll be billed for any instance running, idle or not. App engine is not cheap so be careful.**

Answer (score 0):

`min_instances` applies to the number of instances that you want to have running, from 0 (useful if you want to scale down when you don't receive traffic) to 1000. You are charged for the number of instances you have running, so, this is important to save costs.

For your case set this value to 1, as it's the most straightforward option.