# Best configuration for Automatic Scaling in Google App Engine to always have an instance available?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

What is the best way to set up Google App Engine to always have at least one instance ready and available to handle requests when using automatic scaling? This is for a low traffic application.

There are settings [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements) that allow you to control them but I am not sure what the best combination is and some of them sound confusing. For example, min-instances and min-idle-instances sound similar. I tried setting min-instances to 1 but I still experienced lag.

What is a configuration that from the end user's point of view is always on and handles requests without lag (for a low traffic application)? I

Comment: Are you able to confirm that a new instance was started? If it’s just an issue of a noticeable lag, then it could be due to using a custom domain. See this discussion - https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/sjp9LRzmPH0/m/5xdVRqlNBgAJ

Comment: Did you try `min-idle-instances`? I guess it will match your requirement.

Comment: @N.F. I set both min-instances and min-idle-instances to 1 but sometimes there is still about a 10 second lag if the server has not received any requests in a while.

Comment: @NoCommandLine Yes, it shows the instance is there in the console under "instances". I am not using a custom domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the App Engine Standard environment, when your application load or handling a requests this may cause the users to experience more latency, however `warmup requests` might help you reduce this latency. Before any live requests get to that instance, warmup requests load the app's code onto a new one. If this is enabled, App Engine will detect if your application needs a new instance and initiate a warmup request to initialize a new instance. You can check this link for [Configuring Warmup Requests to Improve Performance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuring-warmup-requests)

Regarding min-instances and min-idle-instances these will only apply when `warmup request` is enabled. As you can see in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52098299/8753991) the difference of these two elements: `min-instances` used to process the incoming request immediately while `min-idle-instances` used to process high load traffic.

However, you mentioned that you don't need a warmup so we suggest you to select App Engine Flexible and based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#:%7E:text=No%2C%20minimum%201%20instance) it must have at least one instance running and can scale up in response to traffic. Please take note that using this environment costs you a higher price. You can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#related_products) for reference regarding the pricing of two environments in App Engine.

Comment: I misspoke when I said "warm up" - I used it to mean turning on an instance. My application does have warm up requests configured as per the link you shared. However, I still get some 10 second lag sometimes when calling an endpoint in the server. This happens when the application has not received traffic for a while.

From your other notes, it seems that having just min-instances set to 1 should avoid that 10 second lag, but I still get it. I wish my application was essentially "always on" so that even if nothing has called the server for an hour, it will still respond fast within ~1 second

Comment: I edited my question to not misuse "warm up"

Comment: Also, if you have min-instances set to 1 and min-idle-instances set to 1, does that mean for billing you will be billed for 2 instances?

Comment: You are charged for the number of instances specified whether they are receiving traffic or not.

Comment: That I understand, but read my question again. Does that count as 2 or 1 instance? That is, can an min-instance also be a min-idle-instance? Or are they seen as two different things.

Comment: App Engine will start calculating the cost in `min-instance` since this instance used to process the incoming request **immediately**. `min-idle- instances` will incur additional costs if there is a sudden load spike or high traffic load.