# Reducing latency in Google App Engine request

Tags: python-3.x, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am looking to add an Authentication endpoint to determine whether a user is logged in. Essentially every single service will call this (either internally or externally). To see what the starting latency of using Google App Engine is, I added a basic endpoint in Flask:

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return 'My Default Service - V1 -- ok!'
```

`app.yaml`

```
service: default
runtime: python39
```

`requirements.txt`

```
Flask==2.1.3
```

And going to the endpoint at https://premiere-stage2.uk.r.appspot.com/ takes on average, about 0.27s. While this is normally a fine response time, I am looking for an ultra-low-latency way to handle a specific endpoint. Taking as a reference, here is doing a search on Algolia:

```
>>> t0=time.time();index.search('xxxxxxxxxx');print(time.time()-t0)
{'hits': [], 'nbHits': 0, 'page': 0, 'nbPages': 0, 'hitsPerPage': 20, 'exhaustiveNbHits': True, 'exhaustiveTypo': True, 'query': 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'params': 'query=xxxxxxxxxx', 'processingTimeMS': 1}
0.03498721122741699
```

The typical response times are about 0.035-0.04s, or about 10x faster than the endpoint I currently have (which is doing nothing).

Are there any ways to improve the latency of a Google App Engine product, or is it just not possible to get to something under 0.1s response time using GAE?

---

Update: I also did the same for a Node environment and got the same response times, around `0.25s`:

`app.js`

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Hello, world!').end();
});

app.listen(8080, () => {});
module.exports = app;
```

`app.yaml`

```
service: default
runtime: nodejs14
instance_class: F4_1G
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: When you run your App, a new instance is created and a new instance always take some time (though I'm surprised this is taking 0.27 if that is the only piece of code you have). But subsequent requests should take less time. Also check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028188/best-configuration-for-automatic-scaling-in-google-app-engine-to-always-have-an

Comment: @NoCommandLine I see. In your experience have you ever been able to get a GAE request to return in under 0.1s?

Comment: @NoCommandLine I set min instances, using warmup and everything and the max instance size and everything, and I consistently get about `0.21s`. Any way to improve that, or is that just the fastest you can get it on GAE?

Comment: I haven't actually ever measured it. I usually focused on making sure the load time was good enough for me especially requests (n + 1) i.e. n + 1 request did not show a noticeable or egregious lag. 

It's possible that you'll still get about 0.2s for something much larger than your ```hello world```. In fact, I just tried our home page https://nocommandline.com and it was fast enough for me (don't think it's less than 0.1s though). 

So the question then becomes - would the request time be a deal breaker or an issue for your users/use case?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that you can take advantage of HTTP's [keep-alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection):

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

With this you can get responses under 0.1s:

```
>>> import time,requests
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> t0=time.time();session.send(requests.Request('GET', url='https://premiere-stage2.uk.r.appspot.com/').prepare());print(time.time()-t0)
<Response [200]>
0.2976038455963135
>>> t0=time.time();session.send(requests.Request('GET', url='https://premiere-stage2.uk.r.appspot.com/').prepare());print(time.time()-t0)
<Response [200]>
0.09582376480102539
```

Now you'll consistently see responses at about `0.95s`.

Comment: ahh, that's a neat trick; will keep this in mind for the future. This will work for your use case (i.e when one is programmatically calling the GAE hosted application). And just to confirm: < 0.1s is still for (n+1) requests, right? Also, I don't think it solves the general case of having a GAE website load in < 0.1s.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can't get 0.1s response times with GAE.  GAE is a general purpose PaaS that works great for a wide variety of web apps.  Most people don't care about the response times you are looking for.

Have you researched how people get such short response times?  I suspect it involves things like pre-rendering content and edge caching.  You can't get that kind of stuff with a hello-world PaaS set up.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've done a bit of research, things like Cloudflare and such offer some 'out-of-the-box' setups for static/js-only pages, and of course there is using multiple servers and load balancing...Are you familiar with any solutions here?