# How to prevent Google Engine app to be shutdown when inactive?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a Java / Spring app running on the standard environment. When inactive, the app is shut down and the next time someone wants to use it he has to wait for a few seconds. I would like to avoid this situation.

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: java17
instance_class: F1

automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 1
```

Comment: You can set `min_instances: 1` in your *automatic_scaling* I guess.

Comment: @DiegoBorba Yes, but the documentation states: "*For this feature to function properly, you must make sure that warmup requests are enabled and that your application handles warmup requests.*", so I'm not sure what to do about that.

Comment: In my opinion, you can implement the [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configuring-warmup-requests?tab=python#top) and then use it, it will just improve your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways to achieve the same and of course each comes with its own implications, primarily *the cost*.

Since you are using scaling type : `automatic`, in that case:

1. You can use

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 1
```

This will keep at least *one* instance running at all times, which can help reduce the startup time for users when they access your application.

**Please note** this setting defines the **minimum number of instances** that should be **running and serving traffic at all times**, regardless of the current level of incoming requests or traffic.

It ensures that there are always at least `min_instances` instances running, which can help reduce startup latency when requests arrive. Use this if you want to ensure a baseline level of availability and responsiveness.

Also, good to know that it is **different** from

```
min_idle_instances
```

which basically defines the **minimum number of instances** that should be kept **in an idle state** (not serving any traffic) during periods of low activity.

These idle instances are ready to handle incoming requests but aren't actively serving any. You can read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092432/what-is-the-difference-between-min-instances-and-min-idle-instances-in-google-ap), to know difference in detail.

> Important to consider, you will need to implement **Warmup** requests

**Warmup requests** `/_ah/warmup` are a specific type of loading request that load application code into an instance ahead of time, before any live requests are made.

I know in the `java8` world of App engine runtime, these are enabled by default, [as also stated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/configuring-warmup-requests).

However, following the [latest documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configuring-warmup-requests?tab=java#top)

First you have to add below in `app.yaml`:

```
inbound_services:
- warmup
```

Followed by defining a *handler* in you application and that could be as simple as:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/_ah/warmup")
public class WarmupController {

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public String warmup() {
        // Perform any initialization or warming up tasks here.
        // This code will be executed when a warmup request is received.
        
        // For example, you can potentially initialize database connections, cache, or other resources, depending on your application features.
        // If there is nothing needed to be initiliased, you may just return "Ok"

        return "Ok! Warmup completed successfully.";
    }
}
```

To learn more about how to use warmup requests, [see Configuring warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/warmup-requests/configuring).

Lastly, also good to mention, since not sure what your application does, but if you want to have a **defined number of instances** , and not use the `automatic` scaling offering, there is also an option of `manual` scaling:

```
runtime: java17
instance_class: F1

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

With manual scaling, you have more control over the number of instances and can ensure that only one or 2 or 3 instance(s) is/are running if that's your requirement.

However, it also means you need to manually manage the scaling and potentially monitor your application's resource utilisation to prevent overloading a single instance.

Hope this information can help you decide what to choose based on your application usage/usecase etc.